# EFcore - multiple untracked instances of same object/entity in a List Property return error about another tracked instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I did not find any resources to this issue, likely cause of wrong wording.

The Setup is an Entity `Lake` which contains a list of `Fish`. Each `Fish` Entity also contains a Entity of its Kind `FishKind`. Via some API I get a `Lake` object already containing a lot of Fish. For some reason there are fish of the same kind -> so therefore we have multiple Objects/instances of the FishKind class which have the same ID.

Here is some dummy code about the Object Hirachy:

```cs
class Lake {
    public int LakeId;
    public List<Fish> Fish;
}
class Fish {
    public int FishId;
    public FishKind Kind;
}
class FishKind {
    public int FishKindId;
    FishKind(int id) { FishKindId = id; }
}
// this is how example data from the API could look like - I don't create objects like this in my code. I get them via the API
// The FishKind have the same id/data however a different instances in C#
// The FishKind have valid IDs which are also already in the DB
// only Lake and Fish should be created
var lake = new Lake();
var idOfShark = 29;
lake.Fish.Add(new Fish("Tony", new FishKind(idOfShark)));
lake.Fish.Add(new Fish("Helen", new FishKind(idOfShark)));
```

For further clarification - example data which is received via API

```json
{
   "LakeId":0,
   "Fish":[
      {
         "FishId":0,
         "Name":"Tony",
         "Kind":{
            "FishKindId":29
         }
      },
      {
         "FishId":0,
         "Name":"Helen",
         "Kind":{
            "FishKindId":29
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

- When I do `db.AddAsync(Lake)` it fails cause I already have this kind of fish added to the DB
- When I try `db.Update(Lake)` it works as long as I don't habe 2 fish of the same kind. If they are of the same kind I get: `The instance of entity type 'FishKind' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{FishKindId: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'`

One workaround that came into my mind is replacing all FishKind Instances with an already tracked Object, however this seems complicated and like a hacky solution.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine I only wrote some minimal code. Fore sure all objects have Ids otherwise I cannot create the migration. I Edited the post to add IDs

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine I don't want to create new FishKind. The Kinds likely are already there form the creation of another lake. (or cause in the GUI when creating a new Fish/Lake I load all Kinds from DB)

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine I don't want to create new Kinds. But I get the objects via Rest, so they differ. The above described workaround would be to lookup all FishKinds and replace them with a tracked obj

Comment: What about the actual code getting the data from the API, any idea why it is creating a new instance of FishKind for each Fish?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine I think this is because asp.net does not know that the objects are the same entities and therefore creates to equal objects but different instances

Comment: Do you have control on this code? When importing a lake from the API, you could try to get the FishKind instance by ID.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine After the conversion of the given json I have control over the code. But I want to avoid loading data from the DB I don't need/already have.

Answer (score -1):

See where you do this:

```
lake.Fish.Add(new Fish("Tony", new FishKind(idOfShark)));
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Don't; you're constantly making new objects with the same ID as an existing object the context already knows about. Either reuse the entity knows about:

```
var shark = context.FishKinds.Single(fk => fk.FishKindId == 29); //if its local it will be returned, if it's not it will be fetched and remembered 

lake.Fish.Add(new Fish("Tony", shark));
lake.Fish.Add(new Fish("Mary", shark));
```

Or upgrade your Fish entity so it has a FishKindId (or whether the column name in the db that maps to the FiskKind PK is) int property and set that to 29 (idOfShark), leave the FishKind entity null.

Comment: This is correct, but I never do `new FishKind(idOfShark)` this is done by the JsonSerializer

Comment: Oh, I see.. Deser'ing to db entities potentially would cause that. I can think of loads of ways to solve built the simplest might be the "put FishKindId in Fish, enumerate fish transferring is from theFish.FishKind.FishKindId into theFisjh.FishKindId and set theFish.FiskKind to null

Comment: (Essentially repairing the object graph to be something the change tracker can tolerate). You could also enumerate the fish replacing all `theFish.FishKind = context.FishKinds.Single(fk => fk.FishKindId == theFish.FishKind.FishKindId)`

Comment: Thanks to your answer I stumbled on `ForeignKey("FishKindId")]` which I'm currently testing out. I can change the API in a way that it only gives me the FishKindId not the full object

Comment: Typo corrections to initial comment: Oh, I see.. Deser'ing to db entities potentially would cause that. I can think of loads of ways to solve built the simplest might be the "put `FishKindId` in `Fish`, enumerate `lake.Fish` transferring ID from `lake.Fish.FishKind.FishKindId` into `lake.Fish.FishKindId` and set `lake.Fish.FishKind` to null